# Is there a database or standard (ISO etc.) which maps Unicode or ISO-15924 scripts with the ISO-639/Glottolog etc. languages that use them

Tags: comparative-linguistics, writing-systems, datasets, standards

Is there a database or standard (ISO etc.) which maps Unicode or ISO-15924 scripts with the ISO-639/Glottolog etc. languages that use them, so that I can make queries like the following on it:
For an ISO-639/Glottolog etc. language, what are the ISO-15924 scripts or Unicode scripts it uses?
For an ISO-15924 or Unicode script, which an ISO-639/Glottolog etc. languages use it?

It will also be nice, for a script, to be able to see a cross-comparison of character occurrences, and how their meanings differ, across languages.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml includes a map from two-letter or three-letter language to four-letter script, under element `languageData`.

```
<languageData>
  <language type="aa" scripts="Latn"/>
  <language type="ab" scripts="Cyrl"/>
  <language type="abq" scripts="Cyrl"/>
```

See documentation https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-info.html#Supplemental_Language_Data

Answer (score 1):

Does [ScriptSource](https://www.scriptsource.org/) meet your needs?

Comment: This post would benefit from adding further details. Being a one-line post, it may attract downvotes and criticism. Please [edit] it to add further relevant information — in particular, you may want to expand on why and how the suggested service may meet the OP's needs.